# Utilizar dois campos em uma relação ManyToOne

Tags: symfony-2, doctrine-2

Existe a seguinte relação entre duas entidades:

```
class Clients
{
    //...

    /**
     * Dealership id
     * 
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dealerships", inversedBy="clients", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @JoinColumn(name="dealership_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $dealershipId;

     //...
}
```

Repare que existe uma relação com a entidade `Dealerships` através do campo `dealership_id`.

Na entidade `Dealerships` tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
class Dealerships
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

     /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="integer")
     */
     private $active;

     //...
}
```

Repare que existe a propriedade `active`.

Se existir um registo com o ID 1 na tabela `Dealerships`, no objeto `clients` basta fazer o seguinte:

```
$client = new Clients();
$client->setDealershipId(1);
```

O código acima funciona porque existe o ID 1, porém na relação quero considerar mais 1 campo, o `active`, ou seja, só aceitar a relação se o campo `active` for igual a 1.

É possível fazer isso utilizando o Doctrine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o mais fácil é buscar o objeto do tipo `Dealerships` pelo `EntityManager` e, caso ele não seja nulo, atribuí-lo ao objeto do tipo `Clients`.

Primeiro buscamos o dealership:

```
$dealership = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT d
        FROM Dealerships d
        WHERE id = :id
        AND active = :active')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->setParameter('active', true)
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Caso esse dealership não seja nulo, basta atribuí-lo ao cliente:

```
if ($dealership instanceof Dealerships) {
    $client = new Clients();
    $client->setDealershipId($dealership->getId());
}
```

(ps: os nomes as classes dos seus modelos deveriam ser no singular, já que costumam manipular um único objeto; além disso, evite manipular id's nas relações entre os objetos).

Comment: Rodrigo, não entendi a sua afirmação de não usar ids nas relações entre objetos. Como assim?

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é que normalmente nas relações entre objetos você pode omitir os id's, o Doctrine é inteligente o bastante para saber como se dá a relação entre um objeto e outro. Prefira usar métodos como `setDealership` e `setClient`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Utilizo o objeto no lugar do ID, mas para simplificar o exemplo eu coloquei logo o ID. Obrigado pela ajuda.